# Multithreading - Not waking up other threads in turn based game. Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm new to multi-threading but ive been asked to make a game. I want each player to take their turn at the same time but not let a player take 4 turns in the time it takes another player take 1 turn.

My run() method currently looks like:

```
public synchronized void run(){  
        while (!gameWon) {
            takeTurn();
            hasPlayerWon();
            playersTurnTaken += 1;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has taken their turn");
            if (playersTurnTaken != n) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            } else {
                playersTurnTaken = 0;
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is inside a nested class called player where the parent class is CradGame and CardGame holds the attribute playersTurnTaken. Im using this variable to find out when each player has taken their turn at it is declared as a volatile variable (I think that's how you should define it).

The output of the program is this however:

```
Thread-3 has taken their turn
Thread-1 has taken their turn
Thread-2 has taken their turn
Thread-0 has taken their turn
Thread-0 has taken their turn
```

and then i'm guessing all threads are waiting as the program does not end.

Why don't they wake up after Thread-0 finishes his first turn? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does `Thread-0` still have the lock, perhaps?  You are synchronizing outside the loop, after all.

Comment: Note that this attempt of synchronization probably does not do anything. `synchronized void run()` synchronizes on the object containing the given `run()` method, so if you have 4 objects, they synchronize separately. Then start waiting on separate objects (the `wait()`-s), and never wake up. In fact it is more surprising that you get two lines from `Thread-0`, as it is expected to get stuck after the first one. Side note: probably this is not the best choice to learn about threading: even after fixing the code you want to have a single player running at a time, which is not real parallelism.

Comment: 1. `wait()` is useless unless another thread synchronizes on the *same object* and calls that object’s `notify` or `notifyAll` method. 2. As [the documentation points out](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long,int%29), `wait()` must be called in a loop based on a condition; other threads should call notify or notifyAll whenever they change that condition. 3. An interrupt occurs when someone else wants your thread to gracefully exit.  Never ignore it; that makes your thread a rogue thread.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. The problem statement here is that the threads need to execute in sequence one by one.

I am guessing you have all the players instance created from a single class and they are all reading a shared variable (volatile).

The points needed to be taken care for this to work.
 - Please use a Atomic variable in place of volatile. Volatile generally is okat when it 
   is a boolean variable.

- Pass this variable in each instance of the player object along with a int variable.

  ```
  AtmomicInteger sharedVariable = new AtomicInteger(1);
  Player player1 = new Player(sharedResource, countToCheck);
  ```
- Now suppose to initiate to initiate player 1 and 2 you have to do below.

  ```
  Player player1 = new Player(sharedResource, 1);
  Player player2 = new Player(sharedResource, 2);
  ```
- Each player run method checks the sharedVariable count with the countToCheck. Once 
  those are equal the run method completes the execution and updates the sharedVariable 
  count to +1.
- The player1 gets checks is the sharedResource value is equal to 1 or not. If yes, it 
  executes and then updates the sharedResource value to 2. From there the player2 will 
  execute the run method, since it was waiting for the sahredResource value to be 2. ... 
  and so on all the player threads that you create will continue to execute..